# Keras: Generating target values based on Faster-RCNN predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**SOLUTION**

Ok, I did find a solution, maybe not the best one. Essentially just created a new method which used the [GradientTape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape) from TensorFlow. Essentially, get the predictions, generate the targets, calculate the losses and then update the gradients.

```py
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    # Forward pass
    y_preds = self.model(x, training=True)
    # Generate the target values from the predictions
    actual_deltas, actual_objectness = self.generate_target_values(y_preds, labels)
    #Get the loss
    loss = self.model.compiled_loss([actual_deltas, actual_objectness], y_preds, regularization_losses=self.model.losses)
# Compute gradients
trainable_vars = self.model.trainable_variables
gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
# Update weights
self.model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
```

I understand that there is better ways to do this with Keras Subclassing, but this did the job.

**ORIGINAL POST**

I am currently trying to create a model, where the prediction is need to be run through a function, which compares them to the training label. This function will then return the target values. How do I train my model, such that the predictions will get fed to my function and it will return the function pred.
I am using Tensorflow 2.1.0 and Keras 2.2.4-tf

Edit:

The model is a modified Faster-RCNN model.
I am trying to add the function, which takes the predictions (a 2xN and a 4xN vector), converts them to bounding boxes, compares them to the ground truth bounding boxes, and then returns what each of the proposed bounding boxes values should have been, in order to overlay this bounding box properly.

Comment: Can you make this more clear, like by giving an example of what training label, target value and your prediction are, are training label and target value same?

Comment: @SajanGohil
Yes, so the model is essentially Faster-RCNN, but with some editions and how to interpret the output.
The output of the model is the traditional Faster-RCNN values (objectness and delta values for anchors).
The prediction are two vectors, a 2xN vector and a 4xN vector. I need to interpret the values from both of these (I already have made this part) return them as the proper target values to the model.

Comment: You should edit your question with this info and change the title such that it reflects your problem better

Comment: Ok I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did find a solution, maybe not the best one. Essentially just created a new method which used the GradientTape from TensorFlow. Essentially, get the predictions, generate the targets, calculate the losses and then update the gradients.

```py
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    # Forward pass
    y_preds = self.model(x, training=True)
    # Generate the target values from the predictions
    actual_deltas, actual_objectness = self.generate_target_values(y_preds, labels)
    #Get the loss
    loss = self.model.compiled_loss([actual_deltas, actual_objectness], y_preds, regularization_losses=self.model.losses)
# Compute gradients
trainable_vars = self.model.trainable_variables
gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
# Update weights
self.model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
```

I understand that there is better ways to do this with Keras Subclassing, but this did the job.